# Mongodb ensureIndex

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mongodb

I am working on Mongodb where I am trying to do the indexing on my collection, it is taking only the range between -140 to 3320000  then the total indexing is coming very high i.e. 23628640 (By using `db.Location.totalIndexSize()`)

Because of that my query is taking more time in execution.

How can I make the indexing between (-180 ,180)? please help me out

```
db.Location.ensureIndex({loc:"2d",type:1,clientId:1,background:true},{min:-140,max:3320000})
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a feature for a partial index (indexing only values from a certain range)? I think not, and even if there is, the way B-trees work, it won't make it any faster (just make the index smaller), so I do not think that your query is taking longer just because the index is big.

Comment: I am not asking for partial indexing, i am asking why my indexing range is going very high, is there any method to make it between (-180,180)

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is wrong. You probably want:

```
db.Location.ensureIndex({loc:"2d",type:1,clientId:1}, {background:true})
```

The min and max options are optional and default to -180 and 180. Do you have any objects that fall outside of that range? It would be helpful to see the error you get and an example object.

Comment: I would like to show my code to you,could you please give me your gmail id thank  you

Comment: In i not specify the range i.e.{min:-140,max:3320000},i am getting   point not in interval of [-180.180] error... please help me out

Comment: are you sure that all of your data is between -180 and 180? I'd suggest querying for values outside of that range. If you have any close values, I'd suggest using a range of -181/181.